# How to add very long Url Key for CMS Page in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, url, content-management-system

I am trying to add a very long url to CMS Page programatically, but URLs are being cut.

Here is my code:

```
$cmsPageData = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'root_template' => 'one_column',
    'identifier' => $endurl,
    'content_heading' => $title,
    'stores' => array(0),//available for all store views
    'content' => $content
);
Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setData($cmsPageData)->save();
```

When $endurl is something like that

"page/98/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.html"

the record is

"page/98/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

How can I use very long URLs?

Comment: I've found in Database in table "cms_page" a field with name "identifier" with type "varchar(100)". May I change it to text or something like that? I know the rule "dont touch the database in Magento" but i cant find another way...

Answer (score 0):

In `core_url_rewrite` table, data type of `request_path` and `target_path` fields are `varchar(255)`.

While in `cms_page` table data type of `identifier` field is `varchar(100)`.

So it's okay to change data type of `identifier` field to `varchar(255)` of `cms_page` table for long URL.

It may not good practice, but if you really needed then you can.